# Why not including twitter bootstrap library in Code-Snippet [ ctrl + M ]

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Twitter bootstrap is heavily used front end framework.

I think this should be added in dropdown list of library inside code-snippet toolbar alongwith Angular, jQuery and others.