# How did this question get answered months before it was asked?

Tags: discussion, answers, merged-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294365/help-us-easily-create-twitter-bootstrap-stack-snippets?cb=1) on meta was asked on 15th May 2015 (on `2015-05-15 08:24:08Z` to be precise) and it has an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281059/1663001) from Christmas Eve 2014 from an anonymous user. Has a mod been playing around on meta perhaps?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/294365/revisions

Comment: Looks like an [older post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281056/why-not-including-twitter-bootstrap-library-in-code-snippet-ctrl-m) was merged with a newer one.

Comment: I found that older question a while after my own one caught traction, but was reluctant to close-vote my own question as a dupe because the other was *a lot* terser. So I flagged for a mod to help, which he/she kindly did by merging the questions.

Comment: @Jeroen I admit it didn't occur to me to look at the revision history of the question. I agree with Mave's comment in the answer below though, perhaps some sort of merge indication would be useful here.

Comment: [alternate theory](http://weknowgifs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/its-magic-shia-labeouf-gif.gif)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When you see things like this it's usually the result of a merge. If you look at the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/294365/revisions) of that question (click on the "edited" time stamp link under the question), you'll see:

> Post Merged (destination) from [meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281056/…](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281056/why-not-including-twitter-bootstrap-library-in-code-snippet-ctrl-m)

This means the answers from [Why not including twitter bootstrap library in Code-Snippet [ ctrl + M ]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281056/why-not-including-twitter-bootstrap-library-in-code-snippet-ctrl-m) were moved over to the newer question.

In this case it probably happened because Martijn felt the newer question had the better question, but the older one's answer was good enough that merging the two together was the most effective way to organize and present the information (with which I agree).

The fact that the user who answered is anonymous isn't actually related to this, it just so happens that the user doesn't currently have an account here for whatever reason.

Comment: This type of merge is confusing, specially for new users.

Comment: A notification inside the merged post saying "This post was merged from another question" wouldn't be amiss.

Comment: @Mave, the people who asked and answered the questions are informed via notifications. People who come across the question later don't really need to know it was merged so long as the answer matches the question.

Comment: @JamesWebster It's not so much the notification that is the issue, it's the confusion caused by the timeline. Also if the source question has the notification on it, why shouldn't the destination?

Comment: @DavidG, The "confusion" about time stamps isn't much of a problem either. I rarely, if ever, compare the question time stamp to the answer time stamp. I pretty much look *exclusively* at the answer time to verify that it's up to date enough. The question time is often immaterial.

Comment: @JamesWebster Well it was enough to confuse me (and I'm a seasoned user) so how do you think a person new to the site would cope?

Comment: Could we do the same to this question, so that this question about older answers is newer than this answer?

Comment: Cool would be if comments could predate the answers/questions to which they are appended.

Comment: @Mave A request for labeling of merged posts would be a good topic for [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/).