# Add a notification/message to merged answers to show it's an older answer from another question

Tags: feature-request, merged-questions

Feature request based on this question: [How did this question (on meta) get answered months before it was asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294543/how-did-this-question-on-meta-get-answered-months-before-it-was-asked?cb=1)

My comment on the accepted answer is: "A notification inside the merged post saying "This post was merged from another question" wouldn't be amiss.", with many votes. There's support for this, and it wouldn't hurt anyone, it would only support usability and reduce questions.

In short:

Questions that have an answer from another question merged into them should have a notification or message saying that the answer was merged from another question, with a link to it.

Comment: I agree there should be a notification, but a link doesn't seem necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The people who are directly involved in the merge, i.e. those who asked and answered the questions *are* informed via notifications.

People who come across the question later don't really need to know it was merged so long as the answer matches the question. I think it's just noise.

The "confusion" about time stamps isn't much of a problem either. I rarely, if ever, compare the question time stamp to the answer time stamp. I pretty much look *exclusively* at the answer time to verify that it's up to date enough. The question time is often immaterial.