# Add note in revision history of questions and/or answers to indicate they were merged and when

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, merged-questions

I thought it was odd that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953756/2630934) answer (as well as others) for a C# question gave Java examples, even though the answers still applied to both languages.  Comments on the question mention that the question was merged, but I can't find any official record of the merge.  It's not even in the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77632/timeline).

Unlike a previous [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/294665/2630934), I don't think this should be indicated directly on the answer, but I do think it should be noted in the history of the question and/or answer.  This would be a useful tool for someone looking to update or remove details of an answer that are specific to the merged question.

Comment: Comments on the question itself make rather clear that it was indeed merged. I agree it is a problem that the revision history makes nary a mention of merge events. At the very least, the question's revision history should show this. It's not in [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/77632/timeline), either.

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't see the merge discussion in the comments of the question.  Also, I didn't know about the timeline feature - it seems handy.  I've updated the question to include these details.  Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like these got merged before that was proper recorded in posthistory: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/530482 but it needs an historian on SE ancient times to confirm  ...

Comment: @rene FWIW [feature changelist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) at MSE says "2010-06-09: [Merged questions are no longer utterly annihilated](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/). A stub is left, just like with closing, and the revision list for the target question keeps better details on merges."